# How to switch a radio button out with a glyphicon

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, radio-button

I am trying to get my radio button to look more "stylish" using bootstrap and I can't figure out how to switch out the stock radio button with bootstrap's glyphicon-unchecked, then switch it to glyphicon-checked when it is clicked on, just like a normal radio button. Here is my code...

```
        <div class="first-draft view">
            <h4>First-Draft</h4>
            <img src="img/view.png" alt="City View"/>
            <h5><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-file"> View Report</span></h5>
            <h6><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-unchecked"> Compare</span></h6>
        </div>
```

I have tried to find different solutions and have come up empty. Is this even possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use radio toggle buttons: http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#buttons-checkbox-radio

JS Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/6561/

```
   <div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons">
  <label class="btn btn-primary active">
    <input type="radio" name="options" id="option1" autocomplete="off" checked> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-unchecked unchecked"></span> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-check checked"></span>
  </label>
  <label class="btn btn-primary">
    <input type="radio" name="options" id="option2" autocomplete="off"> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-unchecked unchecked"></span> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-check checked"></span>
  </label>
  <label class="btn btn-primary">
    <input type="radio" name="options" id="option3" autocomplete="off"> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-unchecked unchecked"></span> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-check checked"></span>
  </label>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.checked{
    display:none;
}
.active .checked {
    display:inline-block;
}
.active .unchecked {
    display:none;
}
```

Comment: is there a way to make it where none can be clicked? So, like be able to unclick one, I guess? See how there is only one in my code? That's really how it is, so I need to be able to check and uncheck it.

Comment: And without the box around it? That is completely throwing off the design of the site I am doing.

Comment: Sure, change the CSS of the buttons, fiddle edited: https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/6562/.  For the "unclick" you can change to checkboxes, but then you also allow multiple to be checked.